# Cannot display image on gridview data binding from local package

Tags: c#, image, gridview, uwp

I have a gridview with data bindings that contain titles and book covers. Cover the book is in the local package with the name of the path: "files/kurikulum 2006/[The name of the folder selected by the user on the previous page]/cover".I have trouble displaying the cover of the book so that the book cover does not appear and the error message appears as below:
[image: error message]

But for the title can be displayed on the gridview.

XAML:

```
<GridView
                x:Name="itemGridView"
                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
                Margin="0,0,10,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
                SelectionMode="None"
                IsSwipeEnabled="false"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick" BorderThickness="0">

                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Height="315" Width="200" Margin="5,10,0,0" Background="White">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="230" Width="180" Source="{Binding Image}" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Name}" />

                            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" >
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="10,10,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,10" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="40" Width="auto"/>
                                </ScrollViewer>

                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
```

Code:

```
ObservableCollection<Book> datasource = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
            StorageFolder _folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            _folder = await _folder.GetFolderAsync("files");
            _folder = await _folder.GetFolderAsync(direktori.Direktori);
            _folder = await _folder.GetFolderAsync(direktori.Name);
            _folder = await _folder.GetFolderAsync("cover");
            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> _files = await _folder.GetFilesAsync(); //which returns List<StorageFile>
            foreach (StorageFile file in _files)
            {
                Book buku = new Book();
                buku.Name = file.DisplayName.ToString();
                StorageFile thumbFile;
                thumbFile = await _folder.GetFileAsync(file.DisplayName.ToString() + ".jpg");
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.SetSource(await thumbFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
                buku.Image = bi;

                datasource.Add(buku);
            }
            itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;
```

Book class:

```
public class Book
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Direktori { get; set; }

        public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
    }
```

How to handle it?

Note:

direktori.Direktori = kurikulum 2006 (or the other folder)

direktori.Name = The name of the folder selected by the user on the previous page

Comment: I think instead of getting the file again in foreach loop you can just use the existing file variable.

Comment: StorageFile thumbFile = file;

Comment: @Saurabh I've tried to replace StorageFile thumbFile with StorageFile thumbFile = file, but still get the same error message and in the same place

Comment: @Rose, I found your same thread on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/fca2b6c8-e8dc-411d-a0da-cc3b2e16e1a9/uwp-c-cannot-display-image-on-gridview-data-binding-from-local-package?forum=wpdevelop) So does barry's answer helped you? Did you resolved?